# Git / SSH trouble - being asked for password

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am using Ubuntu. I am trying to do a Git push to a college server. I have successfully set up git on my college pc. In turn, I saved my private key and added this to my `.ssh` folder on my laptop. When I do a config of Git, it appears as follows:

```
remote.origin.url=git@gitlab.mycollege.com:bosra/LinuxTest.git
```

However when I try to do my first push (as pasted below) I am requested to give a password. There has been no passwords set up. I believe from the config posted that I am using the right protocol. Could anyone suggest what the problem may be here? There are two private keys in my .ssh folder. One generated from the laptop and the other was generated on the college pc. The public key generated on the college pc was added to the server to allow access.

```
bosra@bosra-Apple:~/workspace/LinuxTest$ git push -u origin master
git@mycollege.com's password:
```

Comment: Try specifying it? `ssh://git@gitlab.mycollege.com/bosra/LinuxTest.git`

Comment: Thanks I tried that earlier and I got the following error... ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.mycollege.com:bosra: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Have you added your SSH keys on the server? You create them on your computer but you have to add your public key on the server.

Comment: The public key generated on the college machine was added on the server. The lecturer informed me that I then only needed to take the private key from that key pair and install the private key on my laptop. This has been done. Does my laptop public key also need to be installed on the server?

Comment: Can you simply ssh to the remote machine (without password)? If so, do you have to explicitly specify a password? If not, does ``ssh -v`` give any further relevant information? Does specifying the key using the ``-I`` option to ssh help?

Comment: @JonasWielicki Sorry but I am unclear on how to ssh to the machine in question

Comment: Given that I have two private keys in the .ssh folder, do I need to specify that I an trying to connect with one of the keys in some way??

Comment: @bosra ``ssh git@gitlab.mycollege.com`` would be the command in question. If that doesn't work, you'll want to try adding ``-ipath/to/your/private/key`` (note that its ``i``, not ``I`` as I stated above) to the command line of ssh. Whats the output then?

Comment: @JonasWielicki I have tried to ssh with that command and I am being asked for a password. I have been looking at a website about the path aspect. Can you confirm this is what you mean? http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/11/git-push-with-specific-ssh-key/ ..

Comment: @bosra Exactly. That will do what you need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21570/discussion-between-bosra-and-jonas-wielicki)

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your `ssh-agent` is not running or doesn't have your keys. Try running:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_private_college_key
```

I *believe* this should also start the `ssh-agent` if it's not running. If not, just run `ssh-agent` and try again.